# HTTPListener operation is not supported on this platform

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, httplistener

I just added in a simple `HTTPListener` test to my application. It runs fine on Windows 10 x64, but refuses to run on Server 2008 R2 Standard x64. I am running it as Administrator (otherwise I get "access denied"). I checked that nothing else is trying to bind to the same port (I would get a different error):

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Test
  Public ReadOnly Property Address As String
    Get
      Return _Address
    End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property Port As Integer
    Get
      Return _Port
    End Get
  End Property

  Private _Address As String
  Private _Port As Integer

  Private listener As HttpListener
  Private listenerThread As Threading.Thread

  Public Sub New(ByVal addr As String, ByVal p As Integer)
    _Address = addr
    _Port = p
  End Sub

  Public Sub Start()
    listener = New HttpListener()
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" & Address & ":" & Port & "/")
    listenerThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ListenerThreadSub)
    listenerThread.Start()
  End Sub

  Public Sub ListenerThreadSub()
    listener.Start()
    While listener.IsListening
      Dim response As HttpListenerResponse = Nothing
      Try
        Dim context As HttpListenerContext = listener.GetContext()
        Dim path As String = context.Request.Url.LocalPath
        response = context.Response
        MsgBox(path)
      Catch ex As Exception

      End Try
    End While
    listenerThread.Abort()
  End Sub

  Public Sub Finish()
    listener.Stop()
  End Sub

End Class
```

This is my test button:

```
Private Sub TestToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestToolStripMenuItem.Click
  Dim TestService As Test = New Test("FQDNOFSERVER", PORT)
  TestService.Start()
End Sub
```

Target framework is .NET 4.6.1, but this class seems to be supported since .NET 4. The `IsSupported` property is set to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Some times there are other services using the port, some times the service are disabled.

run with elevation:

**net stop http /y**

**sc config http start= demand**

A restart may be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Okay in my case it was http service problem, but it was deeper.

With @Artur ABC method i saw that i can't start http service again. It was `The configuration registry database is corrupt.`.

I had to go to Registry and `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\`, then i found that ine of binded service is set on my old local ip `192.168.1.54`, when i restarted my network i had a new ip address, and i had to delete old service from registry.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting the "HTTP" driver in Device Manager to "Demand". "HTTP" (along with other Non-PnP) can be found by going to **View > Show Hidden Devices**.

I ran across [this article](https://nbevans.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/websocket-servers-on-windows-server/) that made me wonder if the HTTP driver was enabled.